# Вызов глобальной переменной извне функции

Tags: python, массивы, функции, динамические-массивы

Пытаюсь вывести список извне функции, назначая его глобальным. Но список возвращается пустой, хотя в другой функции я добавляю в него элемент и также назначаю глобальным.

```
messages = []
async def simple(event: userbot.SimpleBotEvent):
    global messages
    messages.append('text')
async def simple(event: bot.SimpleBotEvent):
    global messages
    print(messages)
```

Comment: проблема в том что обе функции имеют одинаковые имена

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы переписали функцию, поэтому функции с изменением массива не существует.